# Restore Sqlserver Database Using C# Showing Error

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am trying to backup and restore sql server 2008r2 database, and i successfully backup my database , But the problem is when i am trying to restore my DB its showing the following error 
 **Restore failed for Server 'XXXX-PC\SQLEXPRESS'**

And Another **important** thing is that , When i Close the DB Connection (From server Explorer [right-click->Close Connection]) its working Normally And Correctly

Below is my Backup And Restore Code
Please help me to fix the problem

```
public static void BackupDatabase(string backUpFile)
{
    ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(@"XXXX-PC\SQLEXPRESS");
    Server server = new Server(con);
    Backup source = new Backup();
    source.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
    source.Database = "testBD";
    BackupDeviceItem destination = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);
    source.Devices.Add(destination);
    //source.Devices.AddDevice(@"G:\MyBackUp.bak", DeviceType.File);
    source.SqlBackup(server);
    con.Disconnect();
}

public static void RestoreDatabase(string backUpFile)
{
    ServerConnection con = new ServerConnection(@"XXXX-PC\SQLEXPRESS");
    Server server = new Server(con);
    Restore destination = new Restore();
    destination.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    destination.Database = "testBD";
    BackupDeviceItem source = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);

    destination.Devices.Add(source);

    destination.ReplaceDatabase = true;

    con.Disconnect();
    server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();

    destination.SqlRestore(server);
}
```

This is the error :
[image]

This is the error message in detail:

[image]

Comment: Look at the inner exception. Please post ex.ToString().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your restore process can't get exclusive access to the database. The Server SMO object has a [KillAllProcesses method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.killallprocesses.aspx) that takes a database as an argument and does what it says on the tin.

Comment: Thanks man.. Its works !!! , i added server.KillAllProcesses("DBName") to my code